# how to get the amazon product price using its name

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

am sorry if it is considered duplicate, but i've tried all python modules that can communicate to Amazon API, but sadly, all of them seems to require the product ID to get the exact price! and what i need is a price from a product name!

lastly, i've tried an extension of [Bottlenose](https://github.com/dlo/bottlenose) its name is [python-amazon-simple-product-api](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) except that it has the same problem: how do i get only the price from the name of a product.

here is what i've tried:

```
product = api.search(Keyword = "playstation", SearchIndex='All')

for i, produ in enumerate(product):
    print "{0}. '{1}'".format(i, produ.title)
```

(this is the same result as using `produ.price_and_currency` which in the example with the file is used with ID)

and then give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\amazon\api.py", line 174, in __iter__
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\amazon\api.py", line 189, in iterate_pages
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\amazon\api.py", line 211, in _query amazon.api.SearchException: Amazon Search Error: 'AWS.MinimumParameterRequirement', 'Your request should have atleast 1 of the following parameters: 'Keywords','Title','Power','BrowseNode','Artist','Author','Actor','Director','AudienceRati g','Manufacturer','MusicLabel','Composer','Publisher','Brand','Conductor','Orchestra','Tex Stream','Cuisine','City','Neighborhood'.'
```

Edit: after correcting `Keyword` to `Keywords` i get a looong time response (infinite loop! and tried it sevral times)! not like returning just the whole XML, but when using only bottlenose, i ony get tags that dont have Price or something...

```
<ItemLink>
  <Description>Technical Details</Description>
    <URL>http://www.amazon.com/*****</URL>
</ItemLink>
```

Update2: it seems that amazon will return `ALL` results, so how to limit this to only the first bucket (because it gives results by **groups of 10 results**)

Comment: Have you tried with 'Keywords' (as mentioned in error message) instead of 'Keyword'?

Comment: yes, and it seems that i got typing errors :p
but the response that a lot of time, how do i get only the min and max price? i repeated it lot of time and it really takes time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay, solved:

pagination is done using `search_n` :

```
test = api.search_n(10, Keywords='example name', SearchIndex='All') # this will return only 10 results
```

[Link](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api/issues/7)

Answer (score 1):

Without having experience with the Amazon API: it's a matter of performing the search properly and intelligently. Think about it carefully, and read through

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html

so that you don't miss any important search feature.

The response contains something between 0 and a zillion of items, depending on how intelligent you search query was. In any case, the items in the response identify themselves via their ASIN, the product ID. Example: `<ASIN>B00021HBN6</ASIN>`

After having collected ASINs via `ItemSearch`, you can perform an `ItemLookup` on these items in order to find further details, like the price.

Comment: it seems that "All" cant get a "MaximumPrice", so the user must specify the type of a product (sadly)